# Suma de los elementos de un arreglo

Tags: javascript

He desarrollado esta función, pero lo que pasa es que, si quiero modificar posteriormente la matriz,  no me serviría, ya que los parámetros de la función deberían de ser más genéricos.

```
function sumaFilas(matriz){
//albergar la suma de los valores
var valor1 = 0;
var valor2 = 0;
var valor3 = 0;
var valor4 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
 valor1  += matriz[0][i];
 valor2 += matriz[1][i];
 valor3  += matriz[2][i];
 valor4 += matriz[3][i];
}
console.log([valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4]);
}
sumaFilas ([
    [0,1,2,3],
    [4,5,6,7],
    [8,9,10,11],
    [12,13,14,15],
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes un array de dos dimensiones, y solo estás usando un único bucle para recorrerlo... cada bucle se encarga de recorrer una única dimensión, así que si queremos recorrer un array de dos dimensiones, necesitamos **DOS BUCLES**!

Usando tu propio código, pero modificándolo para evitar índices hardcodeados, quedaría así:

```js
function sumaFilas(matriz){
  //albergar la suma de los valores
  const resultado = []; // Mejor usar un array que múltiples variables!
  for (let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
   // Primero que nada, para cada nuevo array "interno" vamos a añadir un nuevo 0 a nuestro array de resultados
    resultado.push(0);
    
    /*
    * Ahora estariamos recorriendo el primer array... pero este array está compuesto
    * por otros arrays. Recorrámoslos también!
    */
    for (let j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
      // Recorremos el segundo array sumando los valores al 0 que acabamos de añadir antes
      resultado[i] += matriz[i][j];
    }
  }
  console.log(resultado);
}
sumaFilas ([
    [0,1,2,3],
    [4,5,6,7],
    [8,9,10,11],
    [12,13,14,15],
]);
```

---

Como ves, he añadido un array interno `resultado` para evitar tener variables hardcodeadas. Así da igual que los array que le pases para sumar tengan 3 elementos, 5, o 1000, siempre va a funcionar. También como siempre iteramos sobre la longitud de los array evitando índices hardcodeados no vamos a tener problemas por salirnos de los límites del array o de quedarnos "cortos" sumando elementos.

Recorrer un par de bucles no es algo excesivamente lento así que no tengas miedo a *anidarlos*! Es muy común necesitar tener un par de bucles anidados (incluso es bastante común tener *TRES* bucles anidados. Si necesitas más de tres bucles habitualmente es que hay algo mal diseñado :))

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no sabía que había que crear otro bucle. Y que podía guardar los valores en un único array. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @marioconde La mejor manera de agradecer es marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha ayudado. Además así la pregunta se quedará completa con su respuesta!

Comment: Me parece genial, ¡disculpame! @Benito-B

Answer (score 0):

es mucho más simple, tendrias que estudiar las funciones de arrays. Acá te dejo una solución:

```
let matriz = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11],[12,13,14,15]];
let nuevaMatriz = matriz.map(function(fila){
    let total = 0;
    fila.forEach(num=>{total+=num});
    return total; 
    });
```

Comment: Gracias @Pablito, no sé si me he explicado bien, pero las funciones normalmente se utilizan para reciclar código, he intentado entender como reutilizarlo el parámetro (fila) de la  función, pero he sido incapaz. Asimismo, he de utilizar una estructura de bucle, ya sea for o while. Tampoco me sale el resultado en consola ¿Por qué puede ser? –